# How to open ports in Linux?

Tags: linux, node.js, port, iptables

I am working on a simple Node.js app. This requires a particular port to be open. For example if I want the app to listen to port (say) 5122, I will have to first open the port 5122. For this I have applied the following rule in my iptables

```
iptables -I INPUT 3 --proto tcp --dport 5122 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

Initially this worked for me. But suddenly after some it stopped working.
I now, wanted to check whether the port 5122 is really open or not. I issued the command

```
nmap -sT -O localhost
```

I don’t see any such ports listed here. But

```
sudo iptables -L shows it like this -

ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:5122 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:5122
```

I see this line 2 times. Still confused! No idea.

I now opened the following url http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and entered my host IP and Port and it says, Port 5122 is closed on 50.56.246.162 (which is my host IP)

My question is how do I permanently keep a particular port open for listening.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start running your application (using that port number) for the port to appear as open. As soon as it starts running and successfully listening on Port 5122, a local nmap scan will list that port as being *open*.

You only need to modify firewall rules once your application works to your satisfaction and you want to allow access to it from external host(s).

The output of `iptables -L` shows that your `iptables` command has
successfully modified the firewall rules to allowed external access to your application. In fact, it looks like you inserted the rule twice; this doesn’t do any harm as the second rule won’t be processed.

### Explanation

By default, all TCP and UDP ports are **closed** (not in a *listening state*). Only when a server or similar program opens a **network socket** and starts “listening” to a port number will that port appear to be **open**.

E.g., running `nmap -sT localhost` locally on my server shows that most ports are closed and only lists the ones that are open:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00019s latency).
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

A firewall such as Netfilter / iptables can be used to selectively block
access to ports whether they’re already open or not. In this case, those ports are considered to be **filtered** – though confusingly, some people and websites refer to filtered ports as being “closed” and the act of removing the firewall filter as “opening” a port.

E.g. running `nmap -sT server.name` on the same server from an external host reports different results since now the packets from the remote host are being filtered by the firewall:

```
Interesting ports on server.name (78.47.203.133):
Not shown: 1679 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
```

Note that locally, ports 25 and 3306 are open but from an external perspective they are shown as being **filtered**.